# Can't make multi-line matTooltip, always getting single-line

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

Using [matTooltip]="myMultiLineStringGenerator()" combined with [matTooltipClass]="'my-tooltip'" I was expecting to give me multi-line tooltips, whoever I get one liner tooltip, and I have no control when lines ends and moves to the next line.

Steps to reproduce

HTML part

```
<p  [matTooltipClass]="'my-tooltip'"
    [matTooltip]="getTooltopScript(nearestStations)">
            Hello World!
</p>
```

CSS part:

```
.mat-tooltip {
    white-space: pre-line;
}

::ng-deep .mat-tooltip {
   white-space: pre-line;
}
```

TypeScript

```
getTooltopScript(ns: any[]]){
      let part1 =  ns[0]['stationName'] ;
      let part2 = ns[0]['regionName'];
      return `${part1}.\r\n\
       ${part2}.`;
}
```

I have read a lot other stack flows, and all of them where ending to use whitespace:pre-line in css, and `\r\n` in js\type script to create string. I dont know what else I should do make it work

Please help :)

update in CSS from other stackflows, and first comment below. I still have no result

```
::ng-deep .mat-tooltip .cdk-overlay-container, ::ng-deep .mat-tooltip .cdk- 
    global-overlay-wrapper {
    white-space: pre-line;
}
```

Comment: Can you try to insert the `my-tooltip` class as a child of the `mat-tooltip` class in your CSS selector?

Comment: @Edric:    ::ng-deep .mat-tooltip .my-tooltip .cdk-overlay-container, ::ng-deep .mat-tooltip .my-tooltip .cdk-global-overlay-wrapper {
        white-space: pre-line;
    } DIDN'T work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are having the text coming from ts file, then please find below solution:

In .ts file:

```
getTooltopScript(){
  return 'Multiline Tooltip \n This is second line';
}
```

In HTML:

```
<p #tooltip2="matTooltip" [matTooltip]="getTooltopScript()">Hello World!</p>
```

In css file:

```
::ng-deep .cdk-overlay-container, .cdk-global-overlay-wrapper {
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```

In order to see the tooltip properly, we need to add the material style import in global stylesheet (that is style.css):

In style.css:

```
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';
```

Please find the working example below:

https://angular-sf-tooltip-issue-fix.stackblitz.io

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sf-tooltip-issue-fix?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

Comment: Thank Anoop. Out of curiosity, How should I know that I should import that specific css into my style?

Comment: This worked, instead of adding matTooltipClass with :host, ::ng-deep.

Answer (score 1):

For this to work we need to override the style for **.cdk-overlay-container, .cdk-global-overlay-wrapper**:

```
::ng-deep .cdk-overlay-container, .cdk-global-overlay-wrapper {
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```

In HTML:

```
<p matTooltip="Multiline Tooltip &#13; This is second line">Hello World!</p>
```

Hope this will do the fix for you. Please find the working example below:

https://angular-sf-tooltip-issue-fix.stackblitz.io

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sf-tooltip-issue-fix?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

Comment: Thanks, no success by far, I see you have new class here, [matTooltipClass]="multiline-tooltip". but I dont see it in you css class. Should be there?

Comment: I have updated the my solution with few working links. Please have look at those. [matTooltipClass]="multiline-tooltip" I am not using in my example, so it has no significance.

Answer (score 0):

I know this has been answered but I was able to find a little simpler solution. Using Angular 14 & Material UI 14

**In HTML**

`<div matTooltipClass="l--white-space-pre" matTooltip="'Line 1 of text ' +  '\n' + 'Line 2 of text'></div>`

**In CSS/SCSS at root/app level**

```
.l--white-space-pre{
   white-space: pre-line;
}
```